# Can't set language dynamically once website is deployed

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm website running on .net 6 RC1. I try to set the language dynamically on startup like this:

```
IJSRuntime? jsInterop = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
string? result = await jsInterop.InvokeAsync<string>("userCulture.get");

CultureInfo culture;
if (result != null)
{
    result = result.Replace("\"", "");
    Log.Information($"Loaded Culture: {result})");
    culture = new CultureInfo(result);
}
else
{
    culture = new CultureInfo("de");
}
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Locally it works as expected, even in releas mode. But once I deploy it to the server I get this error:

```
System.AggregateException: AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage (Blazor detected a change in the application's culture that is not supported with the current project configuration. To change culture dynamically during startup, set <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData> in the application's project file.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Blazor detected a change in the application's culture that is not supported with the current project configuration. To change culture dynamically during startup, set <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData> in the application's project file.
```

But I do have that flag set in the csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
      
<BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

So I presume this is somehow stripped out during publish. Any idea how I can prevent that?

Comment: Why do this the user will have their browser set to their language and WASM can detect the language.

Comment: Yeah, we planned to solve it that way. But the customer requirements have us setting it dynamically.